# Sorting an array of JavaScript objects by sub array property/value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I have the following data being returned from a server (the structure of this data is something that I do not have control over)...

```
var data = {
    "TrackingResults": [
        {
            "Name": "Pack One",
            "Products": {
                "Product": [
                    {
                        "ProductName": "Soccer Ball"
                    },
                    {
                        "ProductName": "Tennis Racket"
                    },
                    {
                        "ProductName": "Gold Putter"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "status": "Despatched",
            "Location": "Alabama",
            "Type": "Parcel"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Pack Two",
            "Products": {
                "Product": [
                    {
                        "ProductName": "Backet Ball Hoop"
                    },
                    {
                        "ProductName": "Base Ball Glove"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "status": "Despatched",
            "Location": "Florida",
            "Type": "Parcel"
        }
    ]
};
```

I would like to be able to sort each Tracking Result by the first Product Name.  I can't find any code that will sort by a sub array property/value.

Comment: You will probably need to use `Array.sort()` with a custom `Comparator` !

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `Array.sort` method with a custom comparator function:

```
var resultsComparator = function (res1, res2) {
    var prod1 = res1.Products.Product[0].ProductName;
    var prod2 = res2.Products.Product[0].ProductName;
    return prod1.localeCompare(prod2);
}
```

This way the ordering is based on the current locale of the web browser. You just pass the function to the `sort` method:

```
data.TrackingResults.sort(resultsComparator);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it manually like: (with the hint on localeCompare from [meskobalazs's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857235/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects-by-sub-array-property-value/27857488#27857488) comment)

```
var result = data.TrackingResults.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.Products.Product[0].ProductName.localeCompare(b.Products.Product[0].ProductName)
});
```

This should work for sorting TrackingResults